# Data structure to determine vertex membership after edge removal from a tree in sub-linear time?

Tags: graphs, data-structures, trees, discrete-mathematics

Consider a tree $T = (V,E)$ and its induced disjoint trees $T_1 = (V_1, E_1), T_2=(V_2, E_2)$ by the removal of an edge $e \in E$.
Is there a data structure that enables the immediate determination of membership of vertex $u \in V$? i.e., is $u\in V_1$?

Ideally a data structure with at most polynomial space complexity.

An example is as follows:

I have a tree that I will remove an edge from it to induce a forest of two tree components. Then, I want to attach another edge to reconnect the components to produce a new tree. This procedure is then repeated M times.  I am looking for a data structure that enables this process to run in O(M) time.

Comment: Please augment you question: Do you have any requirements regarding the representations of each *set of vertices*? Why, given an instance of a generic *tree data structure*, wouldn't "the original tree" (with the edge in question removed) and the sub-tree thus disconnected suffice? Does $T$ need to be kept intact?

Comment: @greybeard sorry I don't understand your comment. Suppose we use an adjacency matrix ("generic tree data structure"?) to represent some tree $T$, and continue to use that adjacency matrix for the induced forest. If I point to any node $u \in V(T)$, how could we determine which of the two trees it belongs to in $O(1)$ time? Is this not a requirement already?

Comment: @greybeard I have reworded my question in attempt to address what I think your comment suggests. Thanks for your comment, please let me know if there is anything else I  should clarify.

Comment: Your question sounds like you remove a single edge, only once, in the very beginning. Is that correct? Then you should just precompute for each vertex, which connected component it belongs to.

Comment: @Dmitry it would need to handle one edge removal, but for any edge. this may occur for different trees, thus precomputation is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: I don’t understand your comment

Comment: Basically precomputation isn't possible.

Comment: This doesn’t help me to understand what problem you are trying to solve. It’d be better if you’ve provided some example scenarios in the question

Comment: @Dmitry ah that's a good idea, thanks. i will update the question.

Comment: @Dmitry updated with context

Comment: Is this correct? You repeat the following a bunch of times: 1) User provides an edge, and you remove this edge. This splits the tree into 2 parts: $V_1$ (contains node $1$) and $V_2 = V \setminus V_1$. 2) The user provides vertices $u_1, \ldots, u_k$. For each $u_i$ you should say if it belongs to $V_1$. 3) A user provides an edge $(u,v)$, where $u \in V_1$, $v \in V_2$. You connect the trees using this edge.

Comment: @Dmitry yes that is correct.

Comment: It's too much work to describe it properly, so I'll outline the main ideas: 1) You select a root and use [Euler tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_tour_technique) to represent the tree. 2) Each subtree corresponds to a segment in this tour. You should just remove this segment. Merging requires some work, but is similar. 3) To do the previous operation efficiently, you can use [treaps](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/treap.html). 4) To determine the segment for a subtree, for each node you can store pointers on the leftmost and the rightmost treap node in the tour.

Comment: For merging, you'll have to reorganize tree corresponding to $V_2$, so that the connected node ($v$) becomes a root. Essentially, you'll need to move everything from the left of $left(v)$ to the right of the tree. Again, treaps can do this efficiently.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to describe the operations that the data structure must support.  I'm having a hard time understanding what the requirements are.  Please don't leave information only in the comments.  Instead, revise the question, then flag comments as 'no longer needed' once they are addressed.  We want questions to stand on their own, so that people don't need to read the comments to understand what you are asking.

Comment: While an *adjacency matrix* may be a generic tree representation to a mathematician, coder me was thinking of a [tree data structure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Representations).